# I am looking to match patterns for all wikimedia sites I tried using the following regular expression. But it doesn't match

Tags: php, regex

```
"/wiki*[.]org/i"
```

string : `https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page`

I am parsing the url to extract the host using parse_url() and then running a check with `preg_match()`

```
if(preg_match($blacklistedTemplate, $urlData['host']))
```

The check still seems to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is not a wildcard. It matches 0 or more occurrences of the previous character.

```
wik.org
wiki.org
wikii.org
wikiii.org
```

`.` matches any character:

```
/wiki.*[.]org/i
```

You can check the regex [online](http://regexr.com/3anji)

From `re_format -- POSIX 1003.2 regular expressions`

> An atom is [...] '.' (matching any single character) [...]

and

> An atom followed by '*' matches a sequence of 0 or more matches of the atom.

Answer (score 0):

the "*" (Star, Kleene-Star-Operator) is a QUANTIFIER (0-n times), the "[]" are a definition of a character class (one of the following)...

so your regex translates into:
match: "wik", then match "i" (0-n times), then match any of "." and "org"

that's wrong indeed and must be corrected:

"/wiki.*[.]org/i"

Answer (score 0):

The parse_url() in PHP will return this array:

```
Array ( [scheme] => https [host] => www.wikidata.org [path] => /wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page )
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => nl.wikipedia.org [path] => /wiki/Brainfuck )
```

So a possible solution could look like this:

```
(en|nl|www).wiki.*[.]org
```

Note: for example Wikipedia starts with the language(nl,en,etc) so you will have to add all of them to the list

Comment: Matteo's answer allows me to check for all sub domains without listing out each language. Also we don't need to track new languages that may be added over time.

Comment: Yes, it would. I am going ahead with that one.